# Как создавать кольцевые диаграммы с помощью stroke-dashoffset и stroke-dasharray

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, svg

У меня есть 3 кольцевые диаграммы SVG, на каждой диаграмме есть линия, созданная с помощью Stroke-Dasharray, в целом диаграммы составляют 100%.

Я бы хотел, чтобы каждый график начинался там, где заканчивается последний, чтобы первый график составлял от 0 до 60%. Я бы хотел, чтобы вторая диаграмма начиналась с 60% и доходила до 90%, а последняя диаграмма начиналась с 90% до 100%.

Я пытаюсь сделать это с помощью Stroke DashOffset, но не могу понять, как это работает.

```html
<svg width="15%" height="15%" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="donut">
  <circle class="donut-hole" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="#fff"></circle>
  <circle class="donut-ring" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#d2d3d4" stroke-width="3"></circle>

  <circle class="donut-segment" 
          cx="21" 
          cy="21" 
          r="15.91549430918954" 
          fill="transparent" 
          stroke="green" 
          stroke-width="3" 
          stroke-dasharray="60 40" 
          stroke-dashoffset="25"></circle>
</svg>






<svg width="15%" height="15%" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="donut">
  <circle class="donut-hole" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="#fff"></circle>
  <circle class="donut-ring" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#d2d3d4" stroke-width="3"></circle>

  <circle class="donut" 
          cx="21" 
          cy="21" 
          r="15.91549430918954" 
          fill="transparent" 
          stroke="red" 
          stroke-width="3" 
          stroke-dasharray="30 70" 
          stroke-dashoffset="60"></circle>
</svg>







<svg width="15%" height="15%" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="donut">
  <circle class="donut-hole" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="#fff"></circle>
  <circle class="donut-ring" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#d2d3d4" stroke-width="3"></circle>

  <circle class="donut" 
          cx="21" 
          cy="21" 
          r="15.91549430918954" 
          fill="transparent" 
          stroke="grey" 
          stroke-width="3" 
          stroke-dasharray="10 90" 
          stroke-dashoffset="-"></circle>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Stroke-dashoffset, posiiton stroke-dasharray](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52701491/7394871) от участника  [@ttmt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/668499/ttmt).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/52701491/7394871

Comment: а они не должны на одном круге быть?

Answer (score 0):

Длина окружности - `2 * 3.14 * R`. В данном случае длина окружности будет ~100, что очень удобно.  `stroke-dasharray` - первое число - сколько идет `dash`, второе - сколько идет пропуск. `stroke-dashoffset` указывает откуда начинается график. методом подстановки, вычислил что идет он в обратную сторону, т.е. 25 - это `x: 0, y: 1`, а -25 это `x: 0, y: -1`, а -50 это `x: -1, y: 0` (объясняю на примере тригонометрического круга, надеюсь понятно).

```html
<svg width="15%" height="15%" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="donut">
<circle class="donut-hole" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="#fff"></circle>
<circle class="donut-ring" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#d2d3d4" stroke-width="3"></circle>

<circle class="donut-segment" 
        cx="21" 
        cy="21" 
        r="15.91549430918954" 
        fill="transparent" 
        stroke="green" 
        stroke-width="3" 
        stroke-dasharray="60 40" 
        stroke-dashoffset="25"></circle>
</svg>






<svg width="15%" height="15%" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="donut">
<circle class="donut-hole" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="#fff"></circle>
<circle class="donut-ring" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#d2d3d4" stroke-width="3"></circle>

<circle class="donut" 
        cx="21" 
        cy="21" 
        r="15.91549430918954" 
        fill="transparent" 
        stroke="red" 
        stroke-width="3" 
        stroke-dasharray="30 70" 
        stroke-dashoffset="-35"></circle>
</svg>







<svg width="15%" height="15%" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="donut">
<circle class="donut-hole" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="#fff"></circle>
<circle class="donut-ring" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#d2d3d4" stroke-width="3"></circle>

<circle class="donut" 
        cx="21" 
        cy="21" 
        r="15.91549430918954" 
        fill="transparent" 
        stroke="grey" 
        stroke-width="3" 
        stroke-dasharray="10 90" 
        stroke-dashoffset="-65"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: _объясняю на примере тригонометрического круга, надеюсь понятно_ - не понятно

Comment: @Grundy, https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C

Answer (score 0):

Окружность радиусом r="15,91 равна 2 * 3,1415 * 15,91 = 99,96 =~ 100.

stroke-dasharray="60 40", где

60 - dash (тире)
40 - gap (пробел)

Поскольку по умолчанию — `Stroke-dashoffset = 0`, круг будет начинаться под углом 0 градусов, то есть от положительного направления оси X.
Положительное значение `Stroke-dashoffset = 25` смещает линию против часовой стрелки на четверть круга до пересечения с осью y. То есть зелёная линия теперь будет рисоваться из верхней точки пересечения с осью y.

```html
<svg width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="donut">
  <circle class="donut-hole" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="#fff"></circle>
  <circle class="donut-ring" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#d2d3d4" stroke-width="3"></circle>
<!--  first chart is from 0-60% -->
  <circle class="donut-segment" 
          cx="21" 
          cy="21" 
          r="15.91549430918954" 
          fill="transparent" 
          stroke="green" 
          stroke-width="3" 
          stroke-dasharray="60 40" 
          stroke-dashoffset="25">
  </circle>
```

Отрицательное значение `Stroke-dashoffset = -35` сдвигает второй красный круг по часовой стрелке к концу первой зеленой линии (25-60 = -35).

```html
<svg width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="donut">
  <circle class="donut-hole" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="#fff"></circle>
  <circle class="donut-ring" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#d2d3d4" stroke-width="3"></circle>
<!--  first chart is from 0-60% -->
  <circle class="donut-segment" 
          cx="21" 
          cy="21" 
          r="15.91549430918954" 
          fill="transparent" 
          stroke="green" 
          stroke-width="3" 
          stroke-dasharray="60 40" 
          stroke-dashoffset="25"></circle>
  <!--  второй chart стартует от 60% и идёт до 90% -->  
    <circle class="donut-segment" 
          cx="21" 
          cy="21" 
          r="15.91549430918954" 
          fill="transparent" 
          stroke="red" 
          stroke-width="3" 
          stroke-dasharray="30 70" 
          stroke-dashoffset="-35"></circle> 
   </svg>
```

Отрицательное значение Stroke-dashoffset = -65 сдвигает третий оранжевый круг по часовой стрелке к концу второй красной линии (-35-30 = -65).

```html
<svg width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="donut">
  <circle class="donut-hole" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="#fff"></circle>
  <circle class="donut-ring" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#d2d3d4" stroke-width="3"></circle>
<!--  первый chart  0-60% -->
  <circle class="donut-segment" 
          cx="21" 
          cy="21" 
          r="15.91549430918954" 
          fill="transparent" 
          stroke="green" 
          stroke-width="3" 
          stroke-dasharray="60 40" 
          stroke-dashoffset="25"></circle>
  <!--  второй chart стартует от 60% и идёт до 90% -->  
    <circle class="donut-segment" 
          cx="21" 
          cy="21" 
          r="15.91549430918954" 
          fill="transparent" 
          stroke="red" 
          stroke-width="3" 
          stroke-dasharray="30 70" 
          stroke-dashoffset="-35"></circle> 
    <!--  третий (финальный) chart стартует от 90% до 100%  -->
    <circle class="donut-segment" 
          cx="21" 
          cy="21" 
          r="15.91549430918954" 
          fill="transparent" 
          stroke="orange" 
          stroke-width="3" 
          stroke-dasharray="10 90" 
          stroke-dashoffset="-65"></circle>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57123379/7394871) от участника  [@Alexandr_TT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7394871/alexandr-tt).</sub>

Comment: а что вначале за каша из английского русского?

Comment: _круг будет начинаться под углом 90 градусов, то есть от оси X первого квадранта._ - стоило б еще тут нарисовать, сначала вообще непонятно что за квадранты, какие оси

Comment: _stroke-dasharray_ - а тут можно задавать не абсолютные значения а в процентах или долях от всей длины? Иначе поменяешь радиус и все сломалось вдруг

Comment: @Grundy Я точно не помню на счет процентов и долей для stroke-dasharray. Посмотрю завтра в спецификации SVG. Но как помню, нельзя этого делать. Проверю... Графику могу добавить, это из математики . Первый квадрант - положительные оси `x` и  `y` угол (0-90) Второй квадрант это положительный `x` и отрицательный `y` (90-180) и т.д

Comment: да, я потом уже понял про что это, сначала непонятно как оси расположены

Comment: @Grundy  `stroke-dasharray - а тут можно задавать не абсолютные значения а в процентах?` [Спецификация](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/painting.html#StrokeDashing) позволяет это делать. Но это почти не используются на практике. Так как проценты параметров dasharray пересчитываются в длину отрезков относительно всей ширины холста SVG, а не длины самой линии, как это происходит при указании значений атрибутов в number

Comment: запутался - там точно 360/0 сверху, а не справа где ось `X`?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150119/discussion-between-alexandr-tt-and-grundy).